# Java se "occurred during initialization of VM"

Tags: java

I installed jdk se 32bit on windows 7 x64.
At "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html" for windows.

And I got this error message.

> C:\Users\Administrator>javac -version
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file d:\Program Files (x8
>   6)\prg_java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\rt.jar
>          at java.security.AccessControlContext.(AccessControlContext.java
>   :77)
>          at java.security.AccessController.getStackAccessControlContext(Native Me
>   thod)
>          at java.security.AccessController.getContext(AccessController.java:484)
>          at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:358)
>          at java.lang.Thread.(Thread.java:476)
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\rt.jar

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a space in `d:\Program Files (x8 6)\pr...` between the 8 and the 6? Is that a wrong environment-variable?

Comment: Just a guess: That message was copied from a console with 80 characters width. Windows wraps long lines and does not combine them on copy&paste.

Comment: Does "d:\Program Files (x86)\prg_java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\rt.jar" exist?  Is it readable for the current user?

Comment: We also had this problem in our production server. It could not be a java installation issue. Server was running fine for years..

Answer (score 9):

This problem occurs due to corrupt files in the JAVA SE you are using.

1. Uninstall the jdk you are using
2. Download the jdk setup file (which ever release you need)
3. Install the jdk. Change the env vars correctly.

Now you won't get this error.

Answer (score -1):

**Check and provide path for correct JRE in your eclipse.**

In Eclipse go to `Window-->Preferences`
Then look for `Installed JRE`
Apply current path till JRE from your directory.

Make sure your JRE has necessory jar files
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre(your version)\lib\rt.jar` etc